# How to add month to date in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I am developing one form and i have one textbox with date picker. I am using 720kb date picket pluggin. `https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker` I want users to allow dates after 1 month. For example if today is august 14 then i want to enable dates only after september 14. I have added `moment.js` and put

```
        var date = moment();
        date.add(1, 'months');
        console.log(date);
        $scope.maxdate=date.d;
```

In html i have `date-min-limit="maxdate"`.  How ever this is not going to work. I got `date-max-limit=""` method from the above mentioned document. May i know what i am doing wring in the above code? Can someone help me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: When you say date-min-limit is not going to work, why not? Also can you tell us what about the code above isn't working? Have you tried $scope.maxdate = date; ?

Comment: i tried. but still i am able to select the date. date-max-limit=""2017-08-14T06:10:49.437Z""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date-min-limit="" expects a string version of short date

In your controller

```
$scope.maxdate = moment().add(1, 'M').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

In your html

```
date-min-limit="maxdate"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, you can use this pluggin [https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker,)

In its example，[demos](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox), you can set start date.